# i know that closure can use as variable value.But i am confused which are called this value

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I'm declaring an anonymous function here. In this code I want to know what is the value or expression of variable `$a`.
I thinked it would be `$a = function($x){echo $x;};` or `$a("php")`.

```
$a = function($x){
     echo $x;
};
$a("php");
```

So can you please tell me that what is the variable value in that code?

Comment: I just tried you code, but with `var_dump($a("php"));` and it was NULL as I suspected. The function performs an echo but does not store anything. The function  would need a return value to make a variable assignment for `$a`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to below code

```
function funName ($x) {
    echo $x;
}
funName("php");
```

You are creating an anonymous function (closure) which can de declared by $a. Currently $a is not a variable, it is a closure object. Whenever you want to 
call this function, you need to call $a as a function like

```
$a("$x varibale's value").
```

I hope I got your point correct.